# Не удается подключиться к базе данных через intellij idea

Tags: mysql, база-данных, intellij-idea, jdbc

Пытаюсь подключиться к базе данных через intellij idea, при нажатии на test connection получаю ошибку `Connection to MySQL - mydb@localhost failed. [08001] Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.` Если же попытаться подключиться к базе двойным щелчком,то падает RuntimeException (скрин). При всем этом, через MySQL Workbench или консоль все нормально коннектиться, запросы обрабатываются.
В чем может быть проблема? Буду признателен за любую помощь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это значит что mysql настроить надо в ide

Comment: @InDevX добавил скрины, вроде все настроено

Comment: Ошибку читали/переводили?

Comment: @Bakhuss ну, я вычитал что это проблема с часовым поясом в MySQL и можно попробовать засетить таймзон в my.cnf, но я пока не нашел этот файл у себя, пытаюсь разобраться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
URL:
jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

Только имя 'db' поменять.

Comment: А куда надо это вставить? (я про первый ответ) ибо второй ответ не помог

Answer (score 0):

`SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+2:00';` - помогло решить проблему, все работает